# Get index from template *ngfor for use in my typescript class

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the index of my `*ngFor` inside of my typescript class.
Example :

`*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index";`

How can I send the index value (i) into the component controller ?

Comment: You could send it through via a click method.

Comment: What you want to do with that index?

Comment: Thank you for your question :)
In fact, I want to get elements from my FormArray and add ++1 for the quantity item.
so I imagine that : 
const result = (<FormArray>this.platform.get('elements')).at(index).value 
then {
quantity: result++,
}
I want to get the last data of my item quantity and add 1 quantity.
And that's why I need the index of my itérations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index in your typescript code by sending it with an event. Take this for example:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" (click)="yourFunction(i)">
    {{item}}
</li>
```

When you click on the item, this will send your index to your typescript function.

```
yourfunction(i: number) {
    // Your code here
    alert(i);
}
```

More info about local variables can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables).

Answer (score 2):

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index";>
<a (click)="sendInvoice(i)">Send</a>
</div>
```

TS:

```
sendInvoice(i){
console.log(i);
}
```